# Shell invoked via SQLPLUS.exe HOST command on MSWindows

Tags: oracle, cmd

How does SQLPLUS know which program to invoke (on MS Windows) when the user supplies a HOST command?

(I am looking to replace cmd.exe with something more restrictive, but would rather not break the existing MSWindows installation)

Comment: Do you want to restrict what they can do with `host`, or prevent them doing anything at all?

Comment: Most probably through `%COMSPEC%`

Answer (score 1):

**Identifying the Shell for SQL*Plus**

To identify the shell that SQL*Plus will use when invoking the `HOST` command, it states to set the environment variable, `SHELL`. This is the 12c [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/admn_sqlpls.htm#UNXAR170).

My answer will focus on changing the shell to powershell.

On Windows 7 with Powershell 5.1, I can invoke this command to set my environment variable, `SHELL`, systemically for my laptop:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("SHELL", "powershell.exe" , "Machine")`

Next, I start a SQL*Plus session and I invoke the host command, `host %shell% get-host`.  Here is my execution of this command.

```
SCOTT@db>host %shell% get-host                                                           


Name             : ConsoleHost                                                               
Version          : 5.1.14409.1012                                                            
InstanceId       : b2585ba7-ea5f-452f-ba4f-d3dfc3032890                                      
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface      
CurrentCulture   : en-US                                                                     
CurrentUICulture : en-US                                                                     
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy                        
DebuggerEnabled  : True                                                                      
IsRunspacePushed : False                                                                     
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

Intuitively, one would expect to invoke `host` followed by a shell command (e.g. in my case a powershell command), but this fails:

```
SCOTT@db>host get-host                                                                   
'get-host' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                             
operable program or batch file.
```

Based on these results and removing the need to set the `SHELL` environment variable, this would be similar to my other `host` invocation:

```
SCOTT@db>host powershell get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.14409.1012
InstanceId       : 305716aa-30dc-4ef8-9184-0cfce94254e5
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

---

**Summary**

Perhaps having the environment variable, `SHELL`, identified as a non-default shell works on some non-Windows 7 operating system, this set-up based on documentation has not made a difference.

Outside of SQL*Plus settings and changing environment variables, if you are considering changing the default shell in general on Windows, I see these options:

-Change group policy (e.g. see this [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/replacing-windows-shell-for-everybody-but-the-system-administrator))

-Modify appropriate registry keys based on [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300749(v=winembedded.21).aspx)'s directions.  There are a number of important notes on this link and you need to make sure these directions correspond with the Windows version you are working with.

Comment: Note that the `host` command still works under Windows even if the `SHELL` variable is not defined.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree.